# Webview Not Overriding default browser

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a browser,created using `webview` but whenever I type something into the `textfield` and search it , it fires the default browser. 
also when I click on edit text field to write something and after that, click on the `searchbar` of google's homepage, the keyboard does Not popup, i have to press back button and then again click on the `searchbar` of google's homepage to make keyboard appear.

```
public class Browser extends Activity {
    private EditText urlText;
    private Button goButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview0001);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    urlText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.url_field);
     goButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button);
     goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            openBrowser();
                    }
            });

     urlText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                                    openBrowser();
                                    return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                    }
                    });
}

public void openBrowser(){
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(urlText.getText().toString());
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: question is on the top . please use the scroll wheel of your mouse (Scroll Upwards) or Press The "PageUp" button of your keyboard, it's on the top Right side of your keyboard (Above "PageDown").

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I list several at http://www.andglobe.com. You may have better luck using a site in a language that is more comfortable for you. In English, you have not asked a question.

Comment: i have told my problem instead read FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the WebView to handle navigations itself, you should call WebView.loadUrl() rather than creating an VIEW intent. The documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html may help.

Additionally, you need to implement WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)) with an implementation that returns `false`. By default, WebView will pass URL navigations (e.g. link clicks) to the system for resolution, returning false stops that behaviour.

Comment: where do i implement the WebViewClient.shouldoverrideloading? i have no java experience.

Comment: This page may help you, it has a beginners tutorial for working with the WebVieww: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html